# Subtract data between tables when X Element matches

Tags: c#, sql

The explanation is a little long but I want to make me understand with the problem as detailed as possible. I have 4 tables, 2 indicate the information of material used and material returned (`Transactions` and `Return`s) and the other 2 tablan detail what material was used or was returned (`Trans_det1` and `Devol_det1`)

Each material that is used or not is detailed by `boletas`(tickets), which are detailed by work orders, an example:

I have the following sentences:

```
--REGISTRATION OF INCOME
SELECT*FROM Transa WHERE orden='GORE-999888'

--REGISTRATION OF RETURNS
SELECT*FROM Devol WHERE orden='GORE-999888'
```

It returns this:

[image]

The `Transa` table returns all the tickets that were used for that order and `Devol` also but shows me the `boletas`(tickets) that were used to return material.

**MATERIALS DETAILS**

```
--WHAT WAS USED
SELECT Transa_det1.boleta, Transa_det1.rollo, Transa_det1.cantidad FROM Transa_det1,Transa 
WHERE Transa.boleta=Transa_det1.boleta AND orden='GORE-999888'

--WHAT WAS RETURNED
SELECT Devol_det1.boleta, Devol_det1.rollo, Devol_det1.cantidad FROM Devol_det1, Devol
WHERE Devol_det1.boleta=Devol.boleta AND orden='GORE-999888'
```

It returns this:

[image]

It returns the `rollos` that were used in the tickets from order XXXX and how much was used, the second table shows me the number of `rollos` that were returned.

My question, for the `RT0102` `rollo` I am using `100.5` but then I returned `100` at the end what I really used was `0.5`, same for `RT0103` use `250` but then I returned `50`, there is a way to do the subtraction if the `rollo` match while they are of the same order all in a single query? I mean I need a way to  return this:

```
RT0103 0.5
RT0102 200
FH0091 465.75 //DON'T SUFFER CHANGES BECAUSE I DIDN'T RETURN THIS MATERIAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` like following.

```
SELECT td.boleta, 
       td.rollo, 
       td.cantidad, 
       ( td.cantidad - Isnull(c.ret, 0) ) AS Returned 
FROM   transa_det1 td
       INNER JOIN transa ta
               ON ta.boleta = td.boleta 
       OUTER apply (SELECT top 1 d1.cantidad AS Ret 
                    FROM   devol_det1 d1
                           INNER JOIN devol d
                                   ON d1.boleta = d.boleta 
                    WHERE  d1.rollo = td.rollo and d.orden=ta.orden)c 
where ta.orden = 'GORE-999888'
```

One suggestion, always use `JOINS`, this makes your query more readable and makes it look very clear as to which join corresponds to which condition.

Comment: I have a problem with that code, subtracts values to all amounts even if they are not equal

Comment: can you explain it little more, I am not getting your question.

Answer (score 1):

Below would be the query to get the expected results, You can use case statement for

```
select t1.rollo, 
case when t2.cantidad is null then 0 // if canditad does not have value in DevolDtl then return 0 else do the subtraction 
else t1.cantidad-t2,canditad end as result from
    (
    SELECT Transa_det1.boleta, Transa_det1.rollo, Transa_det1.cantidad FROM Transa_det1,Transa 
    WHERE Transa.boleta=Transa_det1.boleta AND orden='GORE-999888') t1
    left outer join
    (
    SELECT Devol_det1.boleta, Devol_det1.rollo, Devol_det1.cantidad FROM Devol_det1, Devol
    WHERE Devol_det1.boleta=Devol.boleta AND orden='GORE-999888') t2
    on t1.boleta=t2.boleta;
```